# ¿Conectar PHP linux a una base de datos alojada en el s.o windows (DB POSTGRESQL)?

Tags: php, linux, windows, postgresql, ubuntu

Estoy realizando un proyecto `php` en `windows` con un motor de base de datos `POSTGRESQL`, para hacer pruebas del correcto funcionamiento tuve que pasar el proyecto a `linux (virutalbox~ubuntu)` el problema es que no se como conectarme a la base de datos que esta en `windows` mientras trabajo con el proyecto en `linux.`

Agradecería el interés.

Comment: Si la virtualización está en modo puente o enrutamiento interno podrás acceder con la IP que tenga la máquina Windows. Usa `ipconfig` en la máquina Windows para conocer su IP.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia tu respuesta puede ser buena pero muy compleja...ya tengo la ip ¿y ahora?

Comment: Usa esa IP como host donde conectar. También debes comprobar que tu MySQL está escuchando cualquier IP externa, para ello deberás cambiar en el `my.cfg` la línea que pone `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` (o agregarla).

Comment: pero hay un problema, no estoy usando mysql, uso postgresql

Comment: Es igual, los pasos son los mismos (abrir a conexiones externas y configurar que tu aplicación se conecte a la IP de tu equipo). Lo importante es, también, la conectividad de la máquina virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo exista conectividad entre el sistema operativo virtualizado y la PC física, tienes que revisar al menos dos ficheros del SGBD: el `pg_hba.conf` y `postgres.conf`. Estos ficheros están alojados en la carpeta de la instalación del postgresql.
El fichero `postgres.sql` es probable no tengas que modificarlo debido a que por defecto al instalar el SGBD este escucha en todas las interfaces que tenga instalado el SO, pero de todos modos seria bueno que revisaras y la directiva `listen_addresses` la pongas apuntando por ejemplo a la interfaz virtual que creo el software de virtualización; por ejemplo: `listen_addresses = '192.168.1.100'` suponiendo que sea esa la ip de la interfaz que se comunicará con tu sistema virtual.

Ahora bien, el fichero `pg_hba.conf` es el archivo de configuración de la autenticación del servidor, y en el mismo deberás agregar entradas para los host que tendrán acceso a las bases de datos de tu servidor, pudiendo ser una dirección ip o un rango de direcciones ip. Además de establecer a qué base de datos o bases de datos tendrán acceso los clientes. Debes localizar esta sección al final de documento y establecer entradas para las pc que se conectarán a tu servidor, en este caso el sistema virtual

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    postgres,adjudicacion   all             192.168.1.102/32        md5
```

En este caso se especifica que desde el propio sistema donde está instalado el SGBD, todos los usuarios del SGBD tendrán acceso a todas las BD haciendo uso del cifrado `md5` y la segunda entrada especifica que la PC con dirección ip `192.168.1.102` tenrá acceso a la base de datos `postgres` y a la base de datos `adjudicacion` haciendo uso también del cifrado `md5`

Es recomendable antes de realizar algún cambio a este fichero mantener una copia del original para restaurar ante cualquier fallo.
una vez realizado los cambios reinicia el SGBD para que surtan efecto.

Comment: Hola @Francisco esto lo manejo unicamente con la IPv4 que se encuentra dentro del archivo?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta