# ¿Cómo permitir conexiones remotas en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Intenté conectarme de forma remota con un programa hecho en Java, pero aparece el siguiente error:

```
03-19 14:27:32.291 12910-13004/com.example.friky.tdidp D/Mensaje 2 >>>: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no hay una línea en pg_hba.conf para «192.168.150.101», usuario «postgres», base de datos «ventas_oaxaca», SSL inactivo (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO8859_1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

Al parecer es por qué postgreSQL no permite conexiones remotas y debo configurar el archivo **pg_hba.conf** pero no sé cómo se configura.

Comment: Es muy probable te sirva [este hilo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50954/conectar-php-linux-a-una-base-de-datos-alojada-en-el-s-o-windows-db-postgresql/50960#50960)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ve a la siguiente ruta y abre el archivo pg_hba.conf :

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data
```

Encuentra la siguiente línea:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Abajo de la línea anterior agrega lo siguiente:

```
host all all 192.168.150.101/24 md5
```